# error in templates "requires template argument list"

Tags: c++, list, templates, arguments, operators

error C2955: 'math::Array' : use of class template requires template argument list, does anybody have any idea why i take error?

**Array.h**

```
 #ifndef _ARRAY_
 #define _ARRAY_
 namespace math
 {
 template <typename T>
 class Array
 {
 protected:
    //! Flat storage of the elements of the array of type T
    T * buffer;                     
    unsigned int width, height;         

public:
Array & operator = (const Array<T> & source); 
   };

} // namespace math

#include "Array.hpp"
#endif
```

**Array.hpp**

```
  #ifndef _ARRAY_IMPLEMENTATION_
  #define _ARRAY_IMPLEMENTATION_

 namespace math
 {
  template<typename T>
  Array & Array <T>::operator = (const Array<T>& source)
  {
    int size = 3 * getWidth() * getHeight();
    Array<T> buffer = new Vec3<T>[size];
    return *buffer;
  }
 } // namespace math

 #endif
```

Comment: Post a [mcve], please. Context is important.

Comment: I suspect the return value should be `Array<T>&`

Comment: `Array & Array <T>::operator =`... What is the *first* `Array` supposed to be?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i cant change the declaration, only the definition in the Array.hpp file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Array is a class in the header file

Comment: You should not need to change the declaration in the class definition. But you definitely need to change the declaration for the implementation of the function. Copy-paste programming only takes you so far.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do you know how?

Comment: Read the comment by @m.s.

Comment: templates don't go well with .cpp - you'll have to actually include the `Array.hpp` everywhere you want to use it. And what @m.s. said of course.

Comment: @m.s i write return Array<T>& buffer;
how is the correct sydax

Comment: have a look at line 23 @ http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1cfec89f617d3ec

Comment: @m.s it's Array & operator = (const Array<T> & source); 
in the definition you have
-->   Array<T> & Array <T>::operator = (const Array<T>& source)
                  ^

Comment: I think i have to return an Array object so, 
    Array buffer = new Vec3<T>[size];
    return buffer;

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to start with somewhat simpler code for learning C++. There are several errors and problems in your code.

**First**, the **syntax**. `Array` is a *class template* but not a typename, and hence cannot be used as a return type. You must give the fully qualified name, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
Array<T>& Array<T>::operator = (const Array<T>& source);
```

However, within the definition of a template, the template name can be used instead of the fully qualified name, thus you may also say (spot the difference)

```
template<typename T>
Array<T>& Array<T>::operator = (const Array& source);
```

**Second**, the **logic**. Many classes have the *copy assignment* operator `operator=(type const&other)`. The idea is that the value of `*this` is changed to that of `other`. The return value should be `*this`. Thus, in your case ([docu for `std::memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy))

```
template<typename T>
Array<T>& Array<T>::operator = (const Array& other)
{
  const auto alloc = other.width * other.height;
  if(alloc != width*height) {                         // need to re-allocate?
    if(buffer) delete[] buffer;                       //   delete old memory
    buffer = alloc? new T[alloc] : nullptr;           //   allocate new memory
  }
  width = other.width; 
  height= other.height;
  if(alloc)
    std::memcpy(buffer,other.buffer,sizeof(T)*alloc); // copy data
  return*this;
}
```

However, it is strongly recommended to **avoid using `new` and `delete`** operators. Using them efficiently in a exception safe and thread safe way and without memory leaks is (1) non-trivial and (2) better alternatives are provided by the C++ library. Your code, for example leaks memory and fails to initialize `buffer` to `nullptr` in case of default construction (possibly causing segmentation fault).

You could store the data in a [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) data member, or you could have a [`std::unique_ptr<T[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). In the latter case, you may

```
template <typename T>
class Array
{
protected:
  size_t width=0, height=0;              // provide default values; 
  std::unique_ptr<T[]> buffer;
public:
  Array() = default;                     // default constructor: empty
  Array(Array&&) = default;              // move constructor
  Array&operator=(Array&&) = default;    // move assignment
  Array(Array const&other)               // copy constructor
  : width(other.width)
  , height(other.height)
  , buffer(other.buffer? new T[width*height]:nullptr)
  {
    if(buffer)
      std::memcopy(buffer.get(),other.buffer.get(),width*height*sizeof(T));
  }
  Array&operator=(Array const&other)     // copy assignment
  {
    const auto alloc = other.width * other.height;
    if(alloc != width*height)
      buffer.reset(alloc? new T[alloc]:nullptr);
    width = other.width;
    height= other.height;
    if(alloc)
      std::memcopy(buffer.get(),other.buffer.get(),alloc*sizeof(T));
    return*this;
  }
  Array(size_t w, size_t h)     // construct with given width & height
  : width(w), height(h), buffer(w*h? new T[w*h]:nullptr)
  {}                            // leave data uninitialised
  // you don't need to explicitly declare a destructor
};
```

Note the presence of the move constructor and assignment. These can help making code using `Array<>` more efficient.